# sub-shell inside sed

Tags: text-processing, sed

I can append to the start of a file fine with:

```
sed -i '1s/^/word\n/' file
```

I'm [reading](https://askubuntu.com/a/508174/135947) that if I use double quotes I can expand variables, so I try:

```
sed -i "1s/^/$(printenv)\n/" file
```

I end up getting back:

```
sed: -e expression #1, char 15: unterminated `s' command
```

What is happening here. Is it related to the contents of the variable or something else?

Comment: `$(command)` is _not_ a variable...

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/45484256/5318303

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I think the following would work:

```
sed -i '1 e printenv' file
```

From the GNU sed manual:

```
'e COMMAND'
     Executes COMMAND and sends its output to the output stream.  The
     command can run across multiple lines, all but the last ending with
     a back-slash.
```

Alternatively, you can use `cat`, but this requires creating a temporary file:

```
cat <(printenv) file > temporary_file; mv temporary_file file
```

If the package `moreutils` is installed on your machine, you can avoid creating a temporary file manually by using `sponge`:

```
cat <(printenv) file | sponge file
```

Answer (score 5):

To insert the contents *before* line 1:

```
ed -s file <<< $'0r !printenv\nwq'
```

To insert the contents *after* line 1:

```
ed -s file <<< $'1r !printenv\nwq'
```

Answer (score 0):

To more directly answer the OP's question, yes, it is realted to the contents of the sub-shell's output. Bash-recognizable special charaters that retain meaning within double quotes will be interpreted by the shell incorrectly, and `printenv` will give you plenty. What most likely caused that error, an `unterminated 's'` is that the value of `printenv` is many lines long and `sed` expects the s command to be finished by the end of the line. Whatever you want to substitute into that `sed` command would need to be preproccesed to remove or escape out of special characters, replace `newlines` with literal `\n`s, etc.